# Mac OS system restore using Time Machine from bootable USB- Big Sur and later

Tags: time-machine, usb, restore, monterey, bootable-disk

I have a close friend in a rural area whose typical download speed is 6 Mbps. They're running macOS Monterey. System restoration using Time Machine from the internal recovery partition would be expected to be *really* slow.

I have two questions about running Time Machine restore from a bootable USB installer.

1. If you click on Restore Using Time Machine Backup, it erases the destination disk. Does it then use the MacOS installer stored on the USB drive to install a new copy of MacOS, instead of "dialing out" to Apple?
2. If the USB installer is for 12.7.1 and the backup you want to restore in the future is made using 12.7.6, does the system offer to download the delta updater for 12.7.6 so that the restore will work? I know that Migration Assistant won't work until the Mac is updated to the same or newer version of Mac OS.